# How to insert a glossary entries from a different directory file in Latex?

Tags: pdftex, glossaries, directory

I am trying to add a glossary in an appendix in latex.
In the `cls` file, the glossary is configured in the following way:

```
% Generate the Glossary Index
\makeglossaries
% Translates the name of the glossary
\addto\captionsbrazil{% portugues-brasil
    \renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Gloss\'ario}
}

% Glossary Settings Counter
\newcounter{count_glossario}
% Command to simplify the definition of words in the glossary
\newcommand{\newword}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{count_glossario}% Increases the glossary counter
    \newglossaryentry{Def.\arabic{count_glossario}}{%
        name={#1:},%
        description={#2},%
    }%
}

% Changing the glossary name format that appears in the summary
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ABNTEXupperchapter}}{
    \renewcommand{\glssettoctitle}[1]{%
        \renewcommand{\glossarytoctitle}{%
            \texorpdfstring{\MakeTextUppercase{\csname @glotype@#1@title\endcsname}}{\csname @glotype@#1@title\endcsname}
        }
    }
}{}
```

So the new entry is in a `tex/apenx/glossary.tex` file with the following structure:

```
\newword{Word1}{Definition1}
\newword{Word2}{Definition2}
\newword{Word3}{Definition3}
\newword{Word4}{Definition4}
```

I am calling it in the main `.tex` file in the appendix like:

```
\begin{apendicesenv}
\chapter{Glossario}
    \label{chapter:glossario}
    \glsadd{tex/appendix/glossario}
    \printglossaries
\end{apendicesenv}
```

and before the `\begin{document}` there is a `\makeglossaries`,

And when I compile the file using the following compiling code:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm document.aux  document.blg  document.glsdefs  document.ilg  document.loa  document.log  document.loq  document.lot  document.nlo  document.pdf  document.toc document.bbl  document.glo  document.idx document.ist document.lof  document.lol  document.los  document.mw   document.nls document.mw.mw document.synctex.gz document.ind document.fdb_latexmk
pdflatex document.tex
bibtex document.aux
makeindex document.nlo -s document.ist -o document.nls
makeglossaries document.glo
pdflatex document.tex
pdflatex document.tex
okular document.pdf &
```

It doesn't show anything.
can someone help me?
Thank you very much, guys

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem is to add the `\printglossaries` inside the Appendix.